# AngularJS Variable Reference not Getting Populated on ng-click

Tags: html, angularjs

I have the following HTML which should generate a radio button with accompanying text for each element in `regionList`:

```
<div ng-repeat="region in regionList">
    <input type="radio" name="syncType" ng-model="model.syncType" value="REGION_{{region.id}}" />
    <span class="radio-text" ng-click="setSyncType('REGION_{{region.id}}');">Specified Region: {{region.region}} - {{region.projectCount}} Projects</span>
    <br />
</div>
```

The `{{region.id}}` references *appear* to be correctly populated when I inspect within Chrome:

```
<div ng-repeat="region in regionList" class="ng-scope">
    <input type="radio" name="syncType" ng-model="model.syncType" value="REGION_f29a6d22-3bf5-4aa5-a564-b19451548288" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid">
    <span class="radio-text ng-binding" ng-click="setSyncType('REGION_f29a6d22-3bf5-4aa5-a564-b19451548288');">Specified Region: Utah - 12 Projects</span>
    <br>
</div>
```

And when I click the radio button, it works fine. When I click the accompanying text, `setSyncType()` receives the literal string `"REGION_{{region.id}}"`. What am I doing wrong? Or possibly, what should I look for?

Worth mentioning: the `regionList` is populated asynchronously/as part of a Promise, and I still haven't completely wrapped my head around javascript promises. There are other buttons in the radio group that are not part of this regionList, and they display. Then the list refreshes including the regionList radio buttons.

Comment: Protip: replace your spans with divs and eliminate the break tags. (They shouldn't really be used for layout.)

Comment: @isherwood - you put me on the path to a solution! Your alert that my `span` tags were a code smell, I switched to labels, which I've subsequently learned is the proper way to decorate radio button with text and the problem has resolved itself.

Comment: Nice. Go ahead and provide an answer or delete the question.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @isherwood for pointing me in the right direction. Using the appropriate tag, `label`, to decorate a radio button solved the problem:

```
<div ng-repeat="region in regionList">
    <input type="radio" name="syncType" ng-model="model.syncType" id="REGION_{{region.id}}" value="REGION_{{region.id}}" />
    <label for="REGION_{{region.id}}" class="radio-text">Specified Region: {{region.region}} - {{region.projectCount}} Projects</label>
</div>
```